# Ada - does pragma Attach_Handler() can attach handler with System.Priority'Last priority?

Tags: interrupt, ada, protected

The next two declarations are equivalent:

```
protected type prot_Type is
    ....
    pragma Priority(System.Priority'Last);
end;


protected type prot_Type is
    ....
end;
```

One way of attaching interrupt handler is:

```
 protected type prot_Type is
     procedure Handler;
     pragma Attach_Handler(Handler, ...);
 end;

 --//Attach is made at the creation of the next object:
 Object : prot_Type;
```

it's a legal attachment (It works).

How is it possible that the handler has ceiling priority of `System.Priority` Last ? (As far as I know the legal priority is in range Priority'Last+1 .. Any_Priority'Last).

Another thing:
if I add the `pragma Priority(System.Priority'Last);` to the protected declaration, a program_error exception is raised at the elaboration (when attaching the handler).

Someone can please spread the fog?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, I'd suggest posting this question on comp.lang.ada, there's some pretty good expertise over there as well, including some language lawyers and compiler writers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally manage to understand thanks to:
http://www.iuma.ulpgc.es/users/jmiranda/gnat-rts/node33.htm

The fact that an hadler that defined in a protected with ceiling priority System.Priority'Last managed to be attached to Interrupt seems to me like bug in the compiler.

Only hendlers that defined in a protected with ceiling priority in Interrupt_Prioriy'Range can be attached to interrupt.

Another important thing - for non static protected (i.e declared with "protected type ... ") the attachment is made by the creation of the object of that type. The object must be allocated **dynamicly**.

Yony.

Comment: With FSF GCC 7 you get a warning - `pragma Interrupt_Priority is preferred in presence of handlers`

Answer (score 1):

This question is about attaching interrupts (or signals) to a protected object to function as interrupt handlers. It is wonderful that Ada provides you a mostly language-standard way to do this, but there are limits to what is in the standard, and I think your question hits one. You really need to read your compiler's documenation for this one.

For example, if what you are attaching to is an honest-to-god system interrupt, then it is quite possible that your handler will get called directly from the system interrupt, which is of course completely outside of (and thus above) both your OS's process priority and Ada's task priority systems.

Generally in such a case, like with any ISR, you'd want to do the absolute minimum required to make note of and deal with the interrupt, interact with the system as little as possible (no I/O or tasking interactions), and return control back to the system so it can start behaving normally again. In your case, you might want to increment a variable or set a flag internal to your tagged type, take down any volatile info about the interrupt you may need later, then return.